# Winform app, force execute OnLoad Event when focus is on another tab

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForm app, the form has TabControl, control has three tabs tabPage1,tabPage2,tabPage3.

The Tab 'tabPage3' is hosting a User defined control which internally has one or more child controls.
Now my problem lies in tabPage3, 
I know it is a pure Winforms behavior, until your parent is not activated child controls Onload event won't fire.
I have a requirement to force the Onload event to fire when the focus is on tabPage1, tabPage2. Is there any way to force the Onload event to fire.

I have already visited following links but didn't find any clue. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220483/usercontrol-load-event-not-fired)  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131130/how-to-prevent-delay-loading-of-a-usercontrol-in-a-tabcontrol)   [Link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q449250)

Comment: TabPage3 controls won't be initialized until you click on it. Why don't you keep `UserControl` in `Program.cs` file and access it whenever you want.

Comment: I am in a situation the Usercontrol from another library , I can change the library but i cant change the design. As the library is in use by many clients.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very unusual requirement, strongly smells like an XY problem.  The Load event is heavily over-used in Winforms, a side-effect of it being the default event for a Form or UserControl.  One of the behaviors inherited from VB6, the Load event was a big deal in that language.  What you want can easily be accomplished by not giving Winforms a choice:

```
    public UserControl3() {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateHandle();
    }
```

The CreateHandle() call does the forcing, OnLoad will immediately run.  But do be aware that this happens very early, too early to do the kind of things that you'd *really* want to use OnLoad() or the Load event for.  Which are rather limited, it is only truly necessary to discover the actual Location and Size of the control.  Anything else belongs in the constructor.  Surely including the code that you now run in OnLoad().

Strongly favor using the constructor instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for a previous project, for my needs I managed to just iterate over every tab page in the forms constructor (or possibly OnLoad I can't remember) and then reset the index back to 0 before ever showing the end user.

Something similar to:

```
for(int i = 1; i < tabControl.TabCount; i++)
    tabControl.SelectTab(i);
tabControl.SelectTab(0);
```

Comment: I cant do this , the problem i am facing is in close button click of tabPage1, tabPage2. I don't think its a good idea to load all controls of each tab(1...10). I need only tabPage3 child controls to be initialized.

Comment: Its really the only solution unless you can force/ensure the end user selects your tab first. You can just load tab 3 on its own (`SelectTab(2)`)